# Why I do i have the type error? haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types, dictionary

```
applyAll :: [[a] -> [a]]  -> [a] -> [a]
applyAll [] [] = []
applyAll [] a = a   
applyAll (f1:fl) a = applyAll( (drop 1 fl)(f1 a))
```

I got this error

```
Expression     : drop 1 fl (f1 a)         
Term           : drop         
Type           : Int -> [e] -> [e]         
Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d
```

I want to do something like that

```
applyAll [tail, tail, tail, tail] [1,2,3,4,5] = [5],         
applyAll [(map (* 2)), (map (+ 1))] [1,2,3,4,5]) = [3,5,7,9,11]
```

Comment: The compiler error is being caused by a syntax error. Your recursive call to `applyAll` has both its arguments wrapped in parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have

```
applyAll( (drop 1 fl)(f1 a))
```

This is parsed as

```
  applyAll ((drop 1 fl) (f1 a))
= applyAll (drop 1 fl (f1 a))
```

Which tells the compiler that `drop 1 fl` must be a function applied to `(f1 a)`.  However, we know that `drop 1 fl` must return a list, so this obviously is a problem.  As @Lee has pointed out, you want something like

```
applyAll :: [[a] -> [a]] -> [a] -> [a]
applyAll [] a = a
applyAll (f:fs) a = applyAll fs (f a)
```

Although I've merged his first two cases.  You can also give this function the more general type

```
applyAll :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
```

This can alternatively be implemented using `foldr` as

```
applyAll fs a = foldr ($) a fs
```

And then you don't have to worry about base cases at all.  This works because `foldr t b` takes a list and replaces all the `:` in it with `t`, and replaces `[]` with `b`, so in this example:

```
  foldr ($) [1, 2, 3, 4] (replicate 3 tail)
= foldr ($) [1, 2, 3, 4] (tail : tail : tail : [])
--            replace these    ^      ^      ^  ^
--            with $ and replace the empty list |
--            with [1, 2, 3, 4]
= (tail $ (tail $ (tail $ [1, 2, 3, 4])))
= (tail $ (tail $ (tail $ [1, 2, 3, 4])))
= (tail $ (tail $ [2, 3, 4]))
= (tail $ [3, 4])
= [4]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want:

```
applyAll :: [[a] -> [a]]  -> [a] -> [a]
applyAll [] [] = []
applyAll [] a = a     
applyAll (f1:fl) a = applyAll fl (f1 a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like composing the functions in the list, with arguments flipped, compared to usual composition `(.)`

So I'd write :
`applyAll = foldr1 (flip (.))`

I always thought using `($)` as a section is a bit weird, and harder to understand